# In Firefox, from a WebExtension, can I enumerate fonts, and if so, how?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

Use-case, in a Firefox (or soon, other browsers) WebExtension, I want to present the user with a way to customize the font used in parts of the interface.  I want to use fonts that the browser is already aware of, be they installed on 1) the system, or 2) in browser "font cache" (if such a thing exists - e.g. when using CSS `@font-face`, `local( 'Font Name' )` looks for a local cached copy of font, or on system or something).

In Firefox -> Options -> Content -> Fonts & Colors, there is a drop-down selection of fonts that Firefox found on my system.  How can I get this list (and the meta-info about whether it is a serif, sans or mono or other family) for use in a WebExtension?  This seems to be a list of fonts installed on the system.

How might I also get the web-fonts stored in cache somewhere (i.e. web fonts previously downloaded by other pages, the way Google Fonts API does it)?

I'd like to use the meta-info to filter the font list, whitelisting mono or serif fonts that are legible.

Before anyone says, "just include all the font files and serve them up with CSS", I'd just like to say that while technically possible and trivial, it isn't *legally* possible, as most system fonts are mired in intellectual-property usage-restrictions.

And before someone responds, "well, just use *only* open fonts then", I'd also like to say that while I may make some open fonts available, most open fonts are ugly, illegible, or otherwise unsuitable.  And many copyrighted patented trademarked closed-source system fonts are already on the system and look better and also vary by system.  So I'd rather serve up options of fonts to people on specific platforms that they will be familiar and comfortable with.  This may even include foreign language fonts, which open fonts are *severely lacking* at the moment.

And before anyone suggests, "well go make your own multi-lingual open font!!", I'd like to say I already have FontForge, and it's no trivial task to create a font for one language let alone all of them (even if I knew all languages and what constituted an attractive font in each language), though I have hacked a few icon fonts so I technically know how to do it, kind of.

Comment: Gotta remember that browsers actively _fight_ font enumeration, as it's a big fingerprinting opportunity.

Comment: Possible in Chrome extensions: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/fontSettings#method-getFontList

Comment: @Xan Oh, I wasn't aware of that, so it wasn't a matter of remembering, but rather one of learning.  :p  Explains the difficulty finding any information about it in Firefox.  It would be nice if they explained this somewhere.  I'll look into updating the MDN Wiki.  I guess that leaves me with 3 options: 1) Make generic font list assumptions based on whatever platform details I get (problematic), 2) Install only web-fonts so everyone has the same font (slightly ugly), 3) Develop a new open font (labor intense).  Security through obscurity is a failed notion, too bad we pay the price.

Comment: @DanielHerr Thanks for the reference!  Perhaps once I get the Firefox WebExtensions version running, I will port to the Chrome flavor of WebExtensions.  At least then one browser will have fonts tailored for the user.  Unfortunately this feature doesn't seem to exist in Firefox's WebExtensions, perhaps as security through obscurity, as a conscious design decision for various reasons, or merely not enough time to get to it yet.

Comment: Just came up with same problem for me. But my extension mainly works for Chinese / Japanese. Web fonts never works will on these languages. So, maybe I would list the common one and do a filter based on its calculated size. (That's so ugly though)

Comment: @tsh It seemed rather a flawed approach to try to use font lists as the browser makers seem to insist that it is a security vulnerability (via fingerprinting).  I do not agree with that ridiculous assessment, but the reality is that nobody is going to convince them otherwise.  It made my little app significantly larger, but I opted to include all the fonts I will need, and give the user an option to pick from the available fonts.  I used WOFF2 format, converted from WOFF and TTF, recompressed with a high iteration for Brotli for maximum compression.

Comment: @user314159 English require ~100 characters to make it works. But Japanese require at least ~2k characters, and Chinese require about ~10k characters. (Noto Sans CJK, an opensource CJK font, currently support ~45k characters) Due to the same reason, there won't have too mach fonts (especially free to use ones) for me to chose: creating a new font is too expensive.

Comment: @tsh Understood and valid concern.  However, full Latin character set is maybe 200 glyphs?  WOFF2 compressed using Brotli algorithm with a high iteration, the file sizes were 30-150 kbyte each for Normal and Bold, average about 50 kbyte, the size of a small JPEG image.  Assuming a linear file growth, ~45k glyphs is 225x as many characters.  Assuming best and worst case, ~6.75-33MB per font.  If you know beforehand all glyphs that you will use (i.e. user interface strings), you could make an optimized font file using only those glyphs.  Possible to parse messages.json and automate font build.

Comment: It is not very elegant, but it seems we can not reliably get lists of installed system fonts, so these are the options that remain.  Rather than use a sub-optiomal (TTF, OTF, WOFF or WOFF2 but not using Brotli with a high iteration) online font that must download on each and every browser instantiation, it is at least more efficient to download the fonts ahead of time, optimize them as much as possible, and have the user download them only once per add-on download.